# Ionic 2 Navbar Color issue

Tags: cordova, angular, ionic2

I started a blank project in ionic 2. and its working well.

but when i looked into the variables.scss file, i could see an red line error nearby primary:  it says **"[scss] ) expected"**

[image]

I tried to change the colour using this guide http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/theming/theming-your-app/

but it doesn't work. still it shows the same grey color navbar. and also when i googled the issue, everyone referring to use app/app.variables.scss file. but i don't have that file in that location, instead i have them in themes/variables.scss.

[image]
[image]

here is my ionic info. Please advise. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: I had the same issue, scss warning seems to be an editor bug, does creating new colors work?

Comment: Thanks @Ivaro18 for quick response. Yes, i tried using new colors, but sadly, it didn't work. I also tried with different IDE, used WebStorm, i got this same issue. I also tried on my mac, but not able to solve this.

Comment: I'm having `$colors: (
  primary:    #A23C4B,
  secondary:  #32db64,
  danger:     #f53d3d,
  light:      #f4f4f4,
  dark:       #393939,
  favorite:   #69BB7B,
  customRed:    #A23C4B,
  customGrey: #E9EBEE
);`

Comment: I have the same warning but the colors seem to work

Comment: Is your ionic info same as mine?

Comment: Ah didn't see you had final ionic 2

Comment: according to their docs: Colors are no longer added directly to a component, they should instead be passed in the color attribute. So try assigning, instead of `<ion-navbar primary>` do `<ion-navbar color="primary">`

Comment: Great, it works. thank you @lvaro18. please add this as answer. I'll mark it as solved. and one more thing, how'd you know that color="primary" works? Is there any guide on latest release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sass warning 'scss expected' can be ignored, this seems to be an editor bug which will resolve during compile time.

---

Ionic changed it's color because of the following reasons

> - It was difficult to dynamically add colors to components, especially if the name of the color attribute was unknown in the
>     template.
> - This change keeps the css flat since we aren’t chaining color attributes on components and instead we assign a class to the
>     component which includes the color’s name.
> - This allows you to easily toggle a component between multiple colors.
> - Speeds up performance because we are no longer reading through all of the attributes to grab the color ones.

as found [here](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#component-colors).

So to use the colors provided by ionic's sass, change the `<ion-navbar primary>` to `<ion-navbar color="primary">`.

Answer (score 1):

According to version `2.0.0-rc.0 (2016-09-28)`, color has been changed.

[Here](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) you can find the changelog.

> Colors are no longer added directly to a component, they should instead be passed in the color attribute

So for example `<ion-tabs primary>` becomes `<ion-tabs color="primary">`.

Hope I helped you!

**edit**: sorry, posted together...